# Ubuntu 14.04 keeps unmounting my harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, unmount

I am using transmission to download a file and about 5 minutes into the download transmission will say Error: Unable to save resume file: Read-only file system then if I click on any buttons in Ubuntu the desktop will clear and I cannot do anything it is a fresh install of Ubuntu.

Comment: The drive is probably failing. Read-only is likely to be a consequence of that and it doesn't mean it "keeps unmounting".

Comment: In `terminal` type `grep sda /var/log/syslog*` and look for failure messages for your hard drive.

Comment: Duplicate.. The issue has been discussed here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/287021/how-to-fix-read-only-file-system-error-when-i-run-something-as-sudo-and-try-to