# How to solve read only in file system for a windows drive in ubuntu

Tags: filesystem, ssd, disk, read-only

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Recently I added a ssd in my pc. The SSD used for a long time in windows. When I start using that I can't create any file and folder on that drive but I can read all the files. I dont need partition in that and my stored in other drive.

I tried to solve the issue using Disk but it's not work for the disk shows that `dev/sda2:targat in busy`
I have also tried this [how-to-fix-read-only-file-system-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287021/how-to-fix-read-only-file-system-error-when-i-run-something-as-sudo-and-try-to) solution and used `Gparted` to solve the issue but still not solved.

Comment: Try according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867202/internal-hard-drive-mounting-as-read-only/867206#867206): This works if the problem is that Windows is hibernating or semi-hibernating alias using 'fast startup.